# What should I do as a starting freelance web designer/developer?

Tags: price, webmasters

I'm going to start as a freelance web designer in Spain. My concerns are that I don't know how much, what or when to charge my clients.

Would a Wordpress website be more expensive because of its self manageability?
Should I charge half the price in advance just in case the client cancels the project when it is half done?
Should I pay the hostings or should the client do that? Same with premium Gmail accounts.
What about maintenance? Included on the website price or charged periodically?
What things are maintenance and what are redesigns?

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run a web design company in Phuket Thailand, initally you costs need to be reflective of you area (geographical) at home (UK) id charge £400+ for a wordpress site buy here im lucky to get £250 - £300

wordpress sites are less costly as they take less time to develop from your end as all you really doing is taking a template and customising it as opposed to sitting in a room for hours typing out endless streams of HTML

I work on a 35% down to cover theme costs setup charges as i help with domain name purchases - hosting purchases i pretty much take care of everything for the client, this is a good and bad thing in some way as i have complete control over the project and its online presence - however i would not advise taking a contract for less than 35% down

Maintenance is better done as a monthly but to show good faith i usually say if anything goes wrong in the first moth ill take care of it, but i do provide a pdf on how to use the wordpress backend to limit the amount of times im called upon - i have 15 clients that i work with and i get a ton of referral work mainly due to the support and costs i operate on

Maintenance is general upkeep of the site (monthly) redesigns are one off payments and generally cover the entire of the site or at least and good proportion of them

I hope this helps
Gareth